# Associating a view with a form in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a form with several fields. When a user clicks on one of the fields, a div to the side of the form is filled with info about that field and how to best fill it out. This info div is actually a view, and I populate it with the help text by assigning each field a `tip` attribute. The code looks like this:

```
# form field
Em.TextField valueBinding="name" tip="Put the <strong>name</strong> of your organization here."

# views
# Tip Box
Whistlr.TipBoxView = Em.View.extend
  templateName: 'tipBox'
  classNames: ['ember-tip-box']
  content: ""

  actions:

    setContent: (content) ->
      @set 'content', content

# Text field
Em.TextField.reopen
  tip: ''

  click: ->
    Ember.View.views[$(".ember-form-info-box").attr('id')].set 'content', @tip

# template
== view.content
```

This works well enough, but one part of it really bothers me. Specifically, in order to find the tip box view, I search for it like so:  `Ember.View.views[$(".ember-form-info-box").attr('id')]`. This works so long as I only have a single form with a single tip view, but it would break if I had multiple ones. This isn't a problem right now, but might present issues in the future. It also feels hacky.

Is there a more direct way to associate a view with a specific form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an overly complicated way of doing this. Why don't you use something like [jQuery Tooltipster](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/) or [CSS Tooltips](https://github.com/AdamWhitcroft/CSS.Tooltips)?

Comment: Because a number of the tips have links embedded in them, which unfortunately couldn't be accessed with tooltips.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. Tooltipster seems like a great option for this. It has linking ability.

Comment: Yes - you could also manually open and close the tooltip. See the relevant section in the Tooltipster docs.